# How can a WebAPI accept multiple files as parameters?

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I would like to know how/if I can send and accept multiple files (pdf in my case) within the same http request.

I made a POST request in Postman with two files in the body.

What possibilities are there to work with these files in my api? How should the controller look like?

I found IFormFileCollection which looks like it should be the right type, but it didn't work out.

This was my approach.

```
[HttpPost("merge")]
public ActionResult<string> Merge(FormFileCollection files)
{            
    if (files.Count> 0)
    {
        return Ok(files.Count.ToString());                
    }

    return BadRequest("Request failed");
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please avoid sharing links that are critical to the question as these tend to go stale and reduces the value of the StackOverflow database to future users. Also, please include code *as text* in the question itself so people can cut and paste to write your answer. You'll get more answers this way. [ask]

Comment: Please post all code, including errors as code - not images. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for an explanation.

Comment: @KJ Thanks, so I would need to send every file (pdf in my case) separately, store them somewhere and then use them from the storage for further actions, right?